# How to add users to groups in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A newbie Firebase/Android user here, and I am attempting to create an application where users can be added to a group in my Firebase database.

I have defined my User and Group objects as per this post -
 [Group of users in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213006/group-of-users-in-firebase)

My user and group object looks as in the above post and I understand from the documents on Firebase that in order to add a user to a group I need to also add a group reference to a user object but I do not know how I would code this.

I am just unsure of how best to add a User to a Group with Android programatically ,how would I best achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

i think if you familiar with lists you will use it very well as it is very basic one that you have object of group and object of user 
and all you want is to access the user and add the group object 
like this

```
user.getGroups().add(group)
```